# Is there a way to share zsh history among computers just like browser history?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Is there a way to share zsh (shell) history among computers  just like browser history ?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by sharing browser history among computers.

Comment: Storing it on an NFS filesystem works and is something I've done all the time for years.

Answer (score -1):

Hey You can access the zsh  history by typing

`Sudo cat  ~/.zsh history`

And then you will get whole history.
Zsh stores the history in this history file.

[image]

Comment: Something is very wrong if you need `sudo` to access your own history file.